# Why does it fail?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

"Message: Assert.Is True failed. Expected: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...] but found System.Collections.Generic.List`1[...]"

I don't know why is it failing. Can anyone help me with this error please

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Test to Get the all the fee bands from Crm
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Response with a collection of ise_feeband entities</returns>
        [TestCategory("AnnualBillingService")]
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetFeeBandingListTest()
        {
            List<ISE_feeband> fee_bands = new List<ISE_feeband>() { };
            //fee_bands.Add(new ISE_feeband());           
            string entityname = "entity name";
            Guid ID = new Guid();

            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                //Arrange
                ShimCrmService.AllInstances.FetchString = ((@this, fetchXml) =>
                {
                    return new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection()
                    {
                        EntityName = entityname,
                        MoreRecords = true,
                        MinActiveRowVersion = "version",
                        PagingCookie = "paging cookie",
                        TotalRecordCount = 10,
                        TotalRecordCountLimitExceeded = false,
                    };
                });

                //Act              
                var AnnualBillingService = new AnnualBillingService();
                var response = AnnualBillingService.GetFeeBandingList();

                //Assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(response, "Expected not-null response");
                Assert.IsTrue(response.FeeBands == fee_bands, "Expected: " + fee_bands + " but found " + response.FeeBands);
                foreach (var FeeBands in fee_bands)
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(FeeBands.Id == ID, "Expects True");
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the code. I cannot understand the error, its strange that expected and actual result is the same and still getting error.

Comment: code please....

Comment: A guess, you're trying to assert that the result of calling a method from your test produces the expected items, but instead the assert will check that the collections are reference equals, which means they won't be and thus it fails. Or, there are more details in that assert message that you skipped that would tell us why it failed. Either way, you need to provide more information. Right now the only answer we can give is that it fails because you did something wrong.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen beat me to it, most likely reason indeed

Comment: Depending on the type parameter of `List<T>`, you can use [CollectionAssert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert?view=mstest-net-1.2.0) or build your own comparer

Comment: I have updated more information on it. @MKougiouris

Comment: You really should have a look here [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

Comment: This - `response.FeeBands == fee_bands` - will not work the way you intend it. As noted in my first comment, it will do reference comparison, but you want content/value comparison, which has to be done differently. You should look at the unit test framework you're using to see which methods are available to do collection asserts, as they would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is Collection's assert methods, to compare collections of types. There is a difference between `AreEqual` and `AreEquivalent` and i am not pretty sure what your case is here, so take a look at them both!

Follow this link and you will find both methods and their documentation, it should help you enough.
[Clicky clicky](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.areequal?view=mstest-net-1.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Test to Get the all the fee bands from Crm
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Response with a collection of ise_feeband entities</returns>
        [TestCategory("AnnualBillingService")]
        [TestMethod]
        public void GetFeeBandingListTest()
        {
            Guid ID = new Guid();
            List<ISE_feeband> fee_bands = new List<ISE_feeband>();

            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                //Arrange
                ShimCrmService.AllInstances.FetchString = ((@this, fetchXml) =>
                {
                    var output = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityCollection()
                    {
                        EntityName = ISE_feeband.EntityLogicalName,
                    };
                    output.Entities.Add(new ISE_feeband()
                    {
                        Id = ID,                        
                    });
                    return output;
                });

                //Act              
                var AnnualBillingService = new AnnualBillingService();
                var response = AnnualBillingService.GetFeeBandingList();

                //Assert
                Assert.IsNotNull(response, "Expected not-null response");
                Assert.IsTrue(response.FeeBands.Count == 1, "Expected: " + fee_bands + " but found " + response.FeeBands);
                foreach (var FeeBands in fee_bands)
                {
                    Assert.IsTrue(FeeBands.ISE_feebandId == ID , "Expects True");
                }
            }
        }
```

Problem solved guys THANK YOU all :)